# Subdividing a cylinder for sculpting. What is the best way?

Tags: sculpting, subdivision-surface, multiresolution

I have this model which mainly is a cylinder.  The bottom counterweight is boolean added to it and I added loops to make all the vertices fit better.

I would like to subdivide the middle section to be able to sculpt it but I am not managing it.

Subdivision or multiresolution modifiers are totally deforming this simple form which is the one I want.

My end result is to sculpt some bandages around the cylinder in sculpting mode. Any suggestion or should I use another object and then try to boolean it with this part?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest adding one loop cut and slide it up or down the cylinder to where you want your bandages. Then bevel the loop with Ctrl-B using the scroll wheel to increase the number of loops to what you need and moving the mouse to set the required length on the cylinder. You can fine tune that in the bottom-left settings property before you do anything else.